# Data with pair X and Y values

Tags: chart.js

Is it possible to use a the pair X and Y in the `data` option in Chart.js to create the bar char?

```
data: [
    ['08/09/2016', 12],
    ['09/09/2016', 19]
],
```

Being in the form of `[X, Y]`

I didn't find any reference about it in the docs. The closer I got was this found in the [line charts example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-scatter-line-charts):

```
            data: [{
                x: -10,
                y: 0
            }, {
                x: 0,
                y: 10
            }, {
                x: 10,
                y: 5
            }]
```

Comment: Why don't you use the common syntax ? Are you getting the array from an API ?

Comment: @Tektiv indeed I am.

Comment: Also, I'm also used to highcharts, where you can choose both ways for the `data` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in way to create your chart using an array straight into the data.

But you can create a small work around using [Chart.js plugins](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-creating-plugins). They let you handle events triggered during the whole creation of the chart, such as before it is initialized, after a resize, etc.

---

Follows a small plugin that will populate all the data for you using an array :

```js
var myPlugin = {
    // We edit what is happening before the chart is initialized.
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.config.data;

        // `APIarray` is what you get from your API.
        // For every data in this array ...
        for (var i = 0; i < APIarray.length; i++) {
            // Populate the labels array with the first value ..
            data.labels.push(APIarray[i][0]);
            // .. and the data with the second value
            data.datasets[0].data.push(APIarray[i][1]);
        }
    }
};
```

Then you need to add this newly created plugin to your Chart plugin services :

```js
Chart.pluginService.register(myPlugin);
```

---

Make sure to register the plugin **before** creating the chart (*before calling* `new Chart()`), or else it won't work.
I also suggest to have an empty data in your chart (before the plugin occurs) to make sure you won't have data you don't want.

You can see a fully working example [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jffznz8d/).