# How do I access data in an array in an external javascript file to use in a chart using chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
function getWeeklyPay(soc){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.lmiforall.org.uk/api/v1/ashe/estimatePay?soc=".concat(soc),
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var xYears = [];
            var yPay = [];
            console.log(data);
            for(let i=0; i<data.series.length; i++){
                xYears.push(data.series[i].year);
                yPay.push(data.series[i].estpay);
            }
            console.log(xYears);
            console.log(yPay);
        }
    });
}
```

My code above gives me the following values
[image]

And I would like to use this data for my x and y axis on my chart.js as well as the data for the chart but I don't know how to access the data on my HTML page.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: Try following this I believe it might help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39705268/data-with-pair-x-and-y-values

Answer (score 0):

its quite easy, i did it like this for line chart,

```
     <div class="chartCase">
   <canvas id="cases"></canvas>
 </div>
```

you need this ^ for your html, you can css **chartCase** for propr width and height, and chart data will be as following ,

```
let caseChart= document.getElementById("cases").getContext("2d");
 let charts = new Chart(caseChart,{
        type: "line",
        responsive: true, // if you wnat it to be responsive
        //- Data layer start
        data: {
        //- Labels
        labels: X Data here, 

        //- Datasets
        datasets: [
            {
                data: Y Data here ,
                label: "Your Label Name", 
                backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)", // line color
                borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
            },
        ],
    }; 
        //- Data layer end

        //- Options Start
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: true, // if you dont want legends Write False
                position: "top", // legends position
                labels: { // legends label fontsize+ padding
                    fontSize: 14,
                    padding: 4,
                },
            },
            scales: { // customizing X axis and Y axis
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        gridLines: { // this is for X axis grid lines
                            color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                        },
                    },
                ],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        ticks: { // if you want to customize your Y axis 
                            fontSize: 16,
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            callback: function (value) {
                                // if you want a custom function write here.
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        },
        //- Options end
    });
`
```

the same thing for the bar chart, also, if you want more datasets just do this

```
datasets: [
        {
            data: First data here,
            label: "first label",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
            
        },
        {
            data: Second data here,
            label: "second label",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(214, 102, 121, 0.3)",
            borderColor: "rgba(214, 102, 121, 1)",
            
        },
        {
            data: third data here,
            label: "third label",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(113, 255, 47, 0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(113, 255, 47, 1)",
            
        },
```

if you want any other chart check their documentation, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/

Comment: Okay, I've implemented this, I'm getting no errors but the chart isn't displaying

Comment: which chart do you want to implement?